# Get first and rest of string from comma separated values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Given a string like this:

```
"boy, girl, dog, cat"
```

What would be a good way to get the first word and the rest of them, so I could have this:

```
var first_word = "boy";
var rest = "girl, dog, cat";
```

Right now I have this:

`my_string.split(",");` But that gives me all the words that are between the commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both `split` and [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var str = "boy, girl, dog, cat";
var arr = str.split(",");
var fst = arr.splice(0,1).join("");
var rest = arr.join(",");
```

Or similar

```
// returns an array with the extracted str as first value
// and the rest as second value
function cutFirst(str,token){
   var arr = str.split(token);
   var fst = arr.splice(0,1);
   return [fst.join(""),arr.join(token)];
}
```

Comment: these leave a leading space on the `rest`

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) (returning the substring between two indexes or the end of the string) and [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (returning the first position of a substring within another string):

```
var input = "boy, girl, dog, cat",
    pos = input.indexOf( ',' );

console.log( input.substring( 0, pos ) );
console.log( input.substring( pos + 1 ) );
```

Maybe you want to add an [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) call to the results to remove whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to match the two strings before and after the first comma:

```
var v = "boy, girl, dog, cat";
var strings = v.match(/([^,]*),(.*)/);
```

Now `strings` will be a three element array where

- `strings[0]` contains the full string
- `strings[1]` contains the string before the first comma
- `strings[2]` contains everything after the first comma

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to split the array, get first and join the rest:

```js
var my_string = "boy, girl, dog, cat";
var splitted = my_string.split(',');
var first_item = splitted.shift();
var rest_of_the_items = splitted.join(',');

console.log(first_item); // 'boy'
console.log(rest_of_the_items); // 'girl, dog, cat'
```

Comment: Ik  you posted this 10 years ago but i'd have been so helpful if you just had typed the output as a comment

Comment: Hey @Gabriel, I edited the answer. Lmk if it suits.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array in a lazy way and then retrieve just the first element.

```
var ArrayFromString = "boy, girl, dog, cat".split(",");
firstElement = ArrayFromString.pop();
alert(firstElement); //boy
alert(ArrayFromString); //girl, dog, cat​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const my_string = "boy, girl, dog, cat"; 
const splitted = my_string.split(',');
splitted.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

You can also them like an array:

```
console.log(\`This is a ${splitted\[0\]}\`);
```

// expected output: "boy"

// expected output: " girl"

// expected output: " dog"

// expected output: " cat"

Comment: This question is quite old and already has been answered, your answer is very similar to the already approved answer.