# How to access object

Tags: javascript

I want alert object `key` name and its `value`. But it is not working.

```
$(function() {
    var james =  {first: '1,2,3', second: '4,5,6' } 
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert(james[first]) 
    })
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You should correctly use either square bracket notation:

```
alert(james["first"])
```

or dot notation:

```
alert(james.first)
```

to access elements in objects.

**Useful reference:**

- http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html

If you need to display all items in the object use `for` loop with `in` keyword:

```
for (var key in james) {
    // key          -- for key
    // james[key]   -- for value
}
```

Comment: You already have the key - `first`

Comment: ya but i want alert it, second in first's key value i have 3 value what to do if i only want to alert first one

Comment: Can we have choice to select from value

Comment: @JitenderChand I'm not sure that I understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I have two keys "first" and 'second' I want to alert "1" from value

Comment: @JitenderChand Like that: `alert(james.first.split(",")[0]);`?

Comment: Thanks that what i want want

Comment: @JitenderChand Hm... alright :)

Comment: @Jitender: These are questions that would have helped you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341016/get-first-and-rest-of-string-from-comma-separated-values-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-javascript-comma-separated-string-into-an-array. It also helps to actually ask for what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach` to read all property :

```
for (var key in james) {
  alert(key);
}
```